# MongoDB - unable to check if value is $gte val X and $lte val Y

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm doing an aggregate, use `$lookup` to get data from another collection and then use `$filter` in the project-stage to filter the new data.

After getting the new data my output looks like this (`reservations` being the data I get from a different database):

```
 [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_id] => 592fffe7f509270850281871
            [name] => Table 1
            [seats] => 4    
            [reservations] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [_id] => 59367485f5092753f477f2c1
                            [guests] => 3
                            [date] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [$date] => 1496768400000
                                    [$unixtime] => 1496768400
                                    [_datetime] => 2017-06-06 17:00:00
                                )

                            [dateString] => 2017-06-06
                            [duration] => 45
                            [startUTime] => 1496761200
                            [endUTime] => 1496763900
                            [tables] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 592fffe7f509270850281871
                                    [1] => 592fffe7f509270850281874
                                )

                            [reservedAt] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [$date] => 1496740997000
                                    [$unixtime] => 1496740997
                                    [_datetime] => 2017-06-06 09:23:17
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
```

Now I want to filter the reservations. I have a variable called `reqStartTime` and a variable called `reqEndTime`. Those are unixtimes of a newly requested reservation. I want to check if either of those values are in between the `startUTime` and `endUTime` of the current reservations.

Let's say `reqStartTime` is 1496761600 and `reqEndTime` is 1496764200.

Using `$filter` in the project-stage:

```
{
        '$project' : {
            name: 1,
            seats: 1,
            reservations : {
               '$filter': {
                   input : "$reservations",
                   as: "res",
                   cond : 
                        { '$or' : [
                             { '$and' : [
                                { '$gte' : [ reqStartTime, "$$res.startUTime" ] },
                                { '$lte' : [ reqStartTime, "$$res.endUTime" ] } 
                            ]},
                            { '$and' : [
                                { '$gte' : [ reqEndTime, "$$res.startUTime" ] },
                                { '$lte' : [ reqEndTime, "$$res.endUTime" ] } 
                            ]}    
                        ]}
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Problem is, this filters out ALL reservations - the output is always an empty array. I've tested setting the variables `reqStartTime` and `reqEndTime` manually to be sure they're within range, but no luck.

Comment: Would be nicer if you could show the state of the array entries as populated by `$lookup` so there was some data to test conditions against. You are looking for "overlaps" right? Which case is it? Where the supplied parameters "do overlap" or where they "do not overlap"? On the latter that would presumably mean the "booking time" is okay, and an "empty" result of `$filter` would be desired would it not? Thus meaning there was "no overlap".

Comment: @NeilLunn I'm looking for 'overlaps' indeed - I'm trying to get an empty array when there's no overlap, and get the overlapping reservation if there is any. 

However, whatever data I try this with I always get an empty array (even when there should be overlap).

Comment: Like I said, *"can you show us some data please?"* Then this becomes a case where we can reliably test results.

Comment: @NeilLunn lookup gets the only reservation in my reservations-collection (with id: 59367485f5092753f477f2c1). The first piece of data I posted in the question is the output I get directly after doing my $lookup. I'm sorry, but I don't fully understand what extra data you would like.

Comment: @NeilLunn Turns out my variables got converted to string... Thanks for your time tho! I'm going to need some more coffee to start my day.

Answer (score 0):

The query turns out to be a valid one- the problem was that my variables got converted to string. Converting them back to integers fixed the problem.